# Determine, the browser supports canvas (paperjs), or not

Tags: html, canvas, paperjs

Please tell, how can i determine, the browser supports canvas (paperjs), or not ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745432/best-way-to-detect-that-html5-canvas-is-not-supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var canvasExists = document.createElement('canvas').getContext !== undefined;`

Will be `true` in Chrome, `false` in IE8, etc.

You could also check for `window.HTMLCanvasElement !== undefined`

Comment: Thanks very very much Mister Sarris :)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) for html5 canvas support detection. With Modernizr, it is as simple as

```
if(Modernizr.canvas) {
    //HTML5 canvas action
}
```

for reliable and consistent detection across all browsers.