# How do I detect IE 8 with jQuery now that $.browser is deprecated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to detect that HTML5 <canvas> is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745432/best-way-to-detect-that-html5-canvas-is-not-supported)

Now that $.browser [is being taken out of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) in favor of $.support, how would I detect IE8 with jQuery, or with plain javascript?

```
if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 8) {
  alert('IE8'); 
}
```

Sorry, but HTML will not work for me. So I can not do this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ie = 8;
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Specifically, I am looking to do work with the canvas tag and IE8 does not support canvas, but jQuery.support does not detect for canvas support.

Comment: The whole reason for doing this is that you shouldn't *need* to test for IE8. Why are you trying to?

Comment: That link doesn't say its being deprecated, it is just explaining that feature detection is more recommended than browser detection.

Comment: @Tyrsius [It's deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

Comment: @Tyrsius "specific properties may be removed when they are no longer needed internally to improve page startup performance" But still, feature detection is better.

Comment: what do you need to do in IE that is so impossible? the whole point of using jquery is to forget which browser you are working on

Comment: In what feature, specifically, do you need special handling for IE8?

Comment: @Everyone, oh. I stand corrected.

Comment: @BishopZ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745432/best-way-to-detect-that-html5-canvas-is-not-supported

Comment: will help you:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Sometimes people ask the wrong question. This question could have been: "How do I look for a number in a string that is greater than a certain number using a regex?" Why? Because I need to look at a browser agent string. "Why?" Because I need to detect if the browser is greater than IE8. Why? "Because I want to see if canvas is supported." Ah ha! So what you REALLY want to do is see if canvas is supported. Asking for help with your ORIGINAL problem is important. Not to pick on the OP too much :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Test for the feature instead:

```
var el = document.createElement('canvas');
if (el.getContext && el.getContext('2d')) {
    // canvas supported 
}
```

**Edit:**

As in the [link suggested in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2746983/402706) by Brandon Boone, here's a function that does it:

```
function isCanvasSupported(){
  var elem = document.createElement('canvas');
  return !!(elem.getContext && elem.getContext('2d'));
}
```

Comment: From: [Best way to detect that HTML5 <canvas> is not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2746983/402706)

Answer (score 2):

If jQuery doesn't do what you need, I suggest using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) for feature detection instead.

The other option, of course, is simply to stick with the older version of jQuery, before `$.browser` was deprecated. It still works just as well as it always did; no-one is forcing you to upgrade to the latest version.

Finally, you state that you can't edit the HTML so you can't use conditional comments. However, it's worth pointing out that IE also supports a Javascript equivalent to conditional comments. I would assume that you would be able to use this feature.

The following code is taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment) - adapt it as necessary:

```
<script>
/*@cc_on

  @if (@_jscript_version == 10)
    document.write("You are using IE10");

  @elif (@_jscript_version == 9)
    document.write("You are using IE9");

  @elif (@_jscript_version == 5.8)
    document.write("You are using IE8");

  @elif (@_jscript_version == 5.7 && window.XMLHttpRequest)
    document.write("You are using IE7");

  @elif (@_jscript_version == 5.6 || (@_jscript_version == 5.7 && !window.XMLHttpRequest))
    document.write("You are using IE6");

  @elif (@_jscript_version == 5.5)
    document.write("You are using IE5.5");

  @else
    document.write("You are using IE5 or older");

  @end

@*/
</script>
```

Comment: Modernizer is great and what I typically use, but it is not installed on this project. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @BishopZ - I've added other alternative solutions to the answer.