# Detecting canvas text API support (Opera Mini)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, opera-mini, opera-presto

Although Opera Mini does not display canvas text, a typical test indicates that it has an implementation of the text API functions. Is there an alternative technique to check for support?

Current method:

```
var context = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
var canvasTextSupport = typeof context.fillText == "function"; // true in Opera Mini
```

An example you can use to see if text shown: [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=html5-41.htm)

Comment: That's pretty bad on Opera's side — to expose unimplemented method. Have you tried creating a small canvas, filling it with text (just 1 character), and checking if any of the pixels are non-"empty"? It would indicate that text was rendered.

Comment: @kangax sounds promising I will try it out tomorrow and post result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @kangax, you can test by drawing text to a canvas and then making sure that pixels have been drawn.

```
var canvasTextSupported = function() {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");  
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  context.fillText("X", 5, 5);     
  var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 10, 10);

  for(var i = 0, l = imageData.data.length; i < l; i++) {
    if(imageData.data[i] !== 0)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom build of the Modernizr library to do that!

http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Are you sure? I think modernizr also falsely claims support (open http://haz.io/ in OMini).

Answer (score 1):

As I was using `canvas` to detect fonts, with errors thrown, a more compact alternative I found is:

```
var canvasTextSupported = function() {
  var cvs = document.createElement("canvas");  
  var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
  return 'measureText' in ctx && ctx.measureText("") !== undefined;
}
```

Firefox 3.0.x doesn't have `measureText`. And in Opera Mini measureText() returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [canisuse.js](https://github.com/btomashvili/caniuse) script to detect if your browsers supports canvas text API or not

```
caniuse.canvasTextApi();
```