# HTML5 canvas.getContext("2d") in sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm writing Visual WebPart for Sharepoint 2010, and I need use HTML5 canvas.

```
        document.getElementById("testDiv").innerHTML = '<a href="http://c-blues.com">Right</a>';
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        cxt.fillStyle="#000000;
        cxt.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
```

But there is error:

**Runtime error Microsoft JScript: Object does not support property or method "getContext"**

When I try to use this code in ASP.NET web application< it's work fine. What's wrong?\

P.S: all code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<style type="text/css">
.clocks {
    height: 500px;
    margin: 25px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
}
```

```
var canvas;
var ctx;
var clockRadius = 250;
var clockImage;

// функции отрисовки :
function clear() { // очистка
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
}

function drawScene() { // основная функция drawScene
    clear(); // очистка канвы

    // получение текущего времени
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    hours = hours > 12 ? hours - 12 : hours;
    var hour = hours + minutes / 60;
    var minute = minutes + seconds / 60;

    // сохранение
    ctx.save();

    // отрисовка часов (как бэк)
    ctx.drawImage(clockImage, 0, 0, 500, 500);

    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    ctx.beginPath();

    // отрисовка чисел
    ctx.font = '36px Arial';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    for (var n = 1; n <= 12; n++) {
        var theta = (n - 3) * (Math.PI * 2) / 12;
        var x = clockRadius * 0.7 * Math.cos(theta);
        var y = clockRadius * 0.7 * Math.sin(theta);
        ctx.fillText(n, x, y);
    }

    // часы
    ctx.save();
    var theta = (hour - 3) * 2 * Math.PI / 12;
    ctx.rotate(theta);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(-15, -5);
    ctx.lineTo(-15, 5);
    ctx.lineTo(clockRadius * 0.5, 1);
    ctx.lineTo(clockRadius * 0.5, -1);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();

    // минуты
    ctx.save();
    var theta = (minute - 15) * 2 * Math.PI / 60;
    ctx.rotate(theta);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(-15, -4);
    ctx.lineTo(-15, 4);
    ctx.lineTo(clockRadius * 0.8, 1);
    ctx.lineTo(clockRadius * 0.8, -1);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();

    // секунды
    ctx.save();
    var theta = (seconds - 15) * 2 * Math.PI / 60;
    ctx.rotate(theta);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(-15, -3);
    ctx.lineTo(-15, 3);
    ctx.lineTo(clockRadius * 0.9, 1);
    ctx.lineTo(clockRadius * 0.9, -1);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#0f0';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();

    ctx.restore();
}

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        document.getElementById("testDiv").innerHTML = '<a href="http://c-blues.com">Right</a>';
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
       clockImage = new Image();
        //            setInterval(drawScene, 1000);
        cxt.fillStyle="Red";
        cxt.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
    }
    else {
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        cxt.fillStyle="Green";
        cxt.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
        document.getElementById("testDiv").innerHTML = '<a href="http://c-blues.com">Error</a>';
    }
}
// инициализация
window.onload = init;
</script>

<div class="clocks">
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Please provide all the relevant code - you dont show where canvas is declared.

Comment: You didn't post the initialization for the variable canvas. Maybe you have a mistake there, and the variable doesn't actually point to a canvas DOM node?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? canvas is only supported for IE>8

Comment: You have a browser problem, not a sharepoint problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser you are using does not seem to support the `<canvas>` element. The error you posted just shows that the object (canvas) doesn't support the method `getContext`.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745432/best-way-to-detect-that-html5-canvas-is-not-supported) which explains how to check whether your browser supports `canvas`. Actually the answer contains exactly the code you are trying to use to **detect** whether canvas is supported - seems in your case canvas is **not supprted**:

```
function isCanvasSupported(){
  var elem = document.createElement('canvas');
  return !!(elem.getContext && elem.getContext('2d'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
cxt.fillStyle="#000000;
```

**ctx** and **cxt** =)

right

```
ctx.fillStyle="#000000;
```