# Modernizr.canvas not seem to be working

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser, modernizr

I'm currently using [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect HTML5 support in browsers. The script that I'm using looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (Modernizr.canvas) {
      // HTML supported browser
      alert("HTML5 Supported!");
     } else {
      // Not HTML5 supported browser
      alert("Looks like you haven't downloaded chrome yet...");
    }
  });      
</script>
```

And that's obviously after including Jquery-1.9.1. and modernizr.js. When I test in chrome or even IE8 the evaluation always returns as true. When it really shouldn't in IE's case. When I look at my console I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

I've read up on that and the reason being is that '$.browser' has been removed in jQuery 1.9. So what I'm concluding here is that modernizr is still relying on that jQuery function that has been deprecated, am I correct?

In either case, a point in the right direction would be great. I don't even **have** to use modernizr, I just need a way for checking for html5 support.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745432/best-way-to-detect-that-html5-canvas-is-not-supported

Comment: In Modernizr samples, I only see references to jQuery 1.7..

Comment: Not-so-modern modernizr then hey...