# Canvas not supported in IE fires an exception

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html5-canvas

I have a canvas Element:

```
<canvas  id="canvas" width="300" height="300"> 
   Canvas not supported
</canvas>
```

code in .js file:

```
var ct= document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
```

But when I load it in old versions of IE it fires an exception that method `getContext` is not supported.

What I want to do is write something like this:

```
if (!ctx.getContext) ctx = { getContext: function () { } };
```

to get rid of the exception in IE. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is badly structured, and it's hard to see what your plan is - are you just going to check what `getContext()` returns every time you call it?  Why not just check [whether or not it exists in the first place](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/yFrfU/):

```
var ct= document.getElementById('canvas');
if ('getContext' in ct) {
    var ctx = ct.getContext('2d');
    //Rest of code
}
```

Alternatively try one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745432/8655), or use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) for all your feature detection needs.