# HTML 5 > Conditional Comments and Responsive Animation

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements

I have checked the `HTML5 Browser Support` and I must say I'm not very happy BUT I still want to use `HTML5 Animation` in my website.

The thing is that I want to target all the browser versions that don't support `HTML5 Animation` and display only an image of the animation if an older version that the ones supported returns true.

I am aware of `IE Conditional Comments`, and by the chart below, only IE9 and higher support HTML5 so that will be fixed with a :

```
<!--[if lte IE8]>
  <style type=”text/css”>
    IE lower or equal to IE8 Replace animation coding with an image.
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

**HTML5 Browser Support chart**
[image]

***But how do I target let's say Chrome versions lower than 25 or Opera versions lower than 12 ?***

Comment: @t.j.crowder OK, sorry ^^ I will remove the other one :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "HTML5 Animation" you mean you're going to use a canvas, you can readily feature-detect that rather than browser-detecting. Feature detection, whenever possible, is a much better idea.

In this case, you can easily feature-detect canvas support (this particular function is [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2746983/157247)):

```
function isCanvasSupported(){
  var elem = document.createElement('canvas');
  return !!(elem.getContext && elem.getContext('2d'));
}
```

Then in your JavaScript, if `isCanvasSupported()` is falsey, dynamically insert your fallback content instead.

More about feature-detecting:

- http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html
- http://www.modernizr.com

Comment: I guess if I dig into this I can make it happen! Thanks, I'll just have to figure out now how to insert my fallback content and create it ^^

Comment: Thanks, Will look into it. I guess it will take me a while to get focused and get it all together but it's a start ^^

Answer (score 0):

I could do it with a detection pattern so every time your page detects on of those it could use either a different CSS or just another rule.

If you need help tell it here so i could give your more resources