# When the canvas tag is not supported do somehting

Tags: css, html, html5-canvas

For when a browser does not support the canvas tag I show an image.

I have placed this image as a background of a div inside the canvas tag:

```
<canvas width="1200" height="470">
    <div id="wallpaper"></div>
</canvas>
```

The image still downloads though, even if the canvas tag is supported, is there a way to prevent the image downloading to the browser if the canvas tag is supported?

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. But you can test for it the other way around.

Check for a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745432/best-way-to-detect-that-html5-canvas-is-not-supported).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is determine if the browser supports canvas before it is drawn or the image is loaded.  Try using JavaScript like (retrieved from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2746983/3869056):

```
function isCanvasSupported() {
 var elem = document.createElement('canvas');
 return !!(elem.getContext && elem.getContext('2d'));
}
if(!isCanvasSupported())
 document.getElementById('canvas').innerHTML = '<div id="wallpaper"></div>';
```

Of course, this may not be exactly what you want, but it should do the work for you.