# What is fallback for HTML5 canvas tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, html5-canvas

I am working on a project where I have to use HTML canvas for some graphs. But as we know this canvas is not supported in lower versions of Internet Explorer! Is there good fallback for IE, where I can use some different simple technique to show data to user?

Comment: You should probably check out [this stackoverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745432/best-way-to-detect-that-html5-canvas-is-not-supported)

Answer (score 0):

SVG could display graphs. 3d.js for instance uses this. IE9 has support for it.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg