# If browser version is older than

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I have a simple question - is there a way to do some function, that detects if a user is using older browser version, that I can set myself?

Something that help me to do if statement like this:

```
if(chromeVersion <= 48 || firefoxVersion <= 52 || ieVersion <= 10 || ...)
{//do something}
```

I need this because of modern plugins that I'm using and they're not supported by older browsers and can't pre-fix them.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Browser sniffing was a bad idea 10 years ago and it's not got any better. I'd suggest using feature detection if you want to know if your JS code will/will not work in a given browser

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's not much about a javascript. It's about a canvas animations that uses javascript and strong-new css animations (values, ik)

Comment: You can still use feature detection for that too, plus the code is quite simple and much more robust than a version detector: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745432/best-way-to-detect-that-html5-canvas-is-not-supported

Comment: That's also very handy, thanks !! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get chrome version :

```
function getChromeVersion () {     
    var raw = navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(e|ium)\/([0-9]+)\./);

    return raw ? parseInt(raw[2], 10) : false;
}
```

For multiple browser

```js
navigator.sayswho= (function(){
    var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem, 
    M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
    }
    if(M[1]=== 'Chrome'){
        tem= ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);
        if(tem!= null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');
    }
    M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem= ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
    return M.join(' ');
})();

console.log(navigator.sayswho);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need !! :-) Thank you for Chrome ! Anything for Firefox and IE, please?

Comment: @HonzisNovák And what about the hundreds of other browsers out there with varying feature lists?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Sadly we can't cover them all, but I'm glad for 95% covered, 5% is sad lost, if they're old, can't do anything with that I guess

Comment: @HonzisNovák My point is that detecting *feature support* will cover 100% of cases.

Comment: Sorry @NiettheDarkAbsol, 100% browser are not covered.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol , We can try for all browser are detect.

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows

```js
var x = navigator.userAgent.match(/(Opera|Chrome|Safari|Firefox|Msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/);

console.log(x)
if (x[1] == "Chrome") {

  alert("Chrome")

  if (x[2] == "63") {

    alert("Chrome version is 63")

  }



}
```